# Grakn mem issue windows local installation

Tags: vaticle-typedb

I don't have a tech background. I installed grakn locally on windows into a folder, I am able to start the server and use the workbase, however when I tried to do the compute query in the documentation tutorial (social_network), it throws an error:

> 2020-08-18 16:59:33,614 [transaction-listener] ERROR g.c.s.r.SessionService$TransactionListener - Runtime Exception in RPC TransactionListener:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.

I then set env variables:

```
 "SERVER_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx4G
 "STORAGE_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx4G
```

Outcome nok:

> Starting Storage....FAILED!
> Unable to start Storage.
> Process exited with code '1': 'Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>
> An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
> Process exited with code '1': 'Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

I then set env variables:

```
 "SERVER_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx2G
 "STORAGE_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx2G
```

Outcome again nok:

> Starting Storage....FAILED!
> Unable to start Storage.
> Process exited with code '1': ''
>
> An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
> Process exited with code '1': ''

I then set env variables to this:

```
 "SERVER_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx1G
 "STORAGE_JAVAOPTS": -Xmx1G
```

Outcome now is ok:

```
Starting Storage......SUCCESS
Starting Grakn Core Server.....SUCCESS
```

...but why can't I assign more mem? I have totally 32GB and usage is around 20%.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this:

- JVM is unable to allocate 4G of RAM because it's occupied by something else. However, as you've said only 20% or RAM is used, this is an unlikely reason.
- 32-bit JVM are unable to address more than 4GB of RAM [1](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/07/does-32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-matter-anymore/#:%7E:text=In%2032%2Dbit%20JVM%20maximum,the%20limit%20is%20much%20lower), so you should check if it applies to you and reinstall your JVM to be 64-bit if it does.

Comment: I checked again Java installation, indeed, I didnt have 64-bit version. Downloaded 64-bit version and it works now with higher mem allocation. Thanks alot for your help!!!!